# How to set an attribute in a model that doesn't belong to the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4

Inside of my model I have an attribute called `attributes` that its value is taken from the `cutomized_attributes` in my Database the property `attributes` does Not  exist in the Database its just calculated value, while I'm trying to do the following I'm facing this error:

> Error: System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'JToken' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType

Model:

```
public class Restaurant
{
    public int id{ get; set; }
    public string  name{ get; set; }
    public string cutomized_attributes { get; set; }
    private JObject _attributes { get; set; }
    public JObject attributes
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._attributes == null)
                return this._attributes = RestaurantAttributes.parseAttrString(this.cutomized_attributes);
            return this._attributes;
        }
        set
        {
            this._attributes = value;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you are using code first... within the dbcontext subclass

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Entity<Restaurant>().Ignore(x => x.attributes);
}
```

Comment: Or `[NotMapped]public JObject attributes`.